# nobody user running demon

Tags: raspbian, user, process

My raspberry pi has been hacked and as result my samba files have been encrypted by the user nobody. There is a thy demon that keep running in my pi by the user nobody.

[image]

I have been searching triggerhappy demon it is controlling input devices such as keyboard, mouse vs.
I am suspicious that this demon supposed be run by root. any idea ? is this normal ? if it is not how can I change this demon user ?

Comment: Maybe you should have [tried this first?](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=user+nobody&ia=web)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same process.

nobody     264  0.0  0.4   4304  2052 ?        Ss   09:25
0:01 /usr/sbin/thd --triggers
/etc/triggerhappy/triggers.d/ --socket /run/thd.socket
--user nobody --deviceglob /dev/input/event*

As far as I am aware this is normal.

Answer (score 2):

`nobody` is a generic system user for unprivileged system processes.  This is probably normal or a misconfiguration.

> I am suspicious that this demon supposed be run by root.

Running samba root is probably a bad idea as it is outward facing, ie., an attack vector.  If the daemon is hacked via its net interface and is running root, the attacker now has privileged access to your system.  Hence, web servers and the like usually run un-privilleged.

However, because they may require privileges during start-up (eg., to open a low number port), they often start as root and once that stuff is done, drop privileges by switching to another uid (such as `nobody`).